# how to store session value in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, cookies

I have one login page and its database. i want to take the email from there and store it in another table of the same database. Code is give below please have a look and tell me.

Table 1

```
<?php
session_start();
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

include 'connection.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($res);

if($count == 0)
{
    echo "Username Password Incorrect";
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    header("location:home2.php")
}
?>
```

Table 2

```
<?php

$email= (HOW TO GET IT FROM SESSION?)

$company = $_POST['company'];
$project = $_POST['project'];
$duration = $_POST['duration'];
$key_learning = $_POST['key_learning'];

include 'connection.php';

$sql = "INSERT INTO `internship`(`id`, `email`, `company`, `project`, `duration`, `key_learning`) VALUES ('', '$email', '$company','$project', '$duration', '$key_learning')";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($res);

if($count == 1)
{
    echo "Fail";
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    header("location:home3.php");
}

?>
```

From table 1 i want to take email if using session and want to store it in table 2. How to do it?

Comment: OH NOOOOOO!!!! DONT USE MYSQl. Use mysqli instead

Comment: $email=$_SESSIOn["email"] ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $email= (HOW TO GET IT FROM SESSION?)

If the 2nd code block is in the same execution context as the first,  you can just use the variable `$email` that you created.

If you're trying to retrieve data from session as the user navigates to a new page, you do:

```
<?php
session_start();
$email = isset($_SESSION['email'])? $_SESSION['email'] : null;
```

By the way, in the 2nd code block you're trying to use `mysql_num_rows` to analyze the effect of an `INSERT` query. You can't do that.  [According to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php):

> [mysql_num_rows] retrieves the number of rows from a result set. This
>   command is only valid for statements like SELECT or SHOW that return
>   an actual result set. To retrieve the number of rows affected by a
>   INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query, use mysql_affected_rows().

```
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_affected_rows()){
   //success
}else{
  //failure
}
```

You should not be using `mysql_` functions anyway and you should most definitely not be inserting user provided values (username, email, password) directly in your SQL statement